# Encountered two children with the same key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm really new to react and redux development. I have a list component that is connected to a container. I want to update a list on scroll but i get:

```
Encountered two children with the same key
```

My component:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import Track from './Track'
import styles from './TrackList.css'

const altImg = require('../images/sc.jpg');

export default class TrackList extends Component  {

  static propTypes = {
    tracks: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.number.isRequired
      }).isRequired).isRequired,
    onTrackListScroll: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }

 render() {
    const { tracks, onTrackListScroll } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
      <ul className='tracks'
        onScroll={(e)=>{
          console.log('SCROLL!!',e)
          onTrackListScroll()
        }}>
        {tracks.map(track =>
          <Track
            key={track.id}
            {...track}
            //onClick={() => onTrackClick(track.id)}
            text={track.title}
            imgSrc={!track.artwork_url ? altImg : track.artwork_url}
          />
        )}
      </ul>
      </div>
    )

  }
}
```

reducer that update a state is :

```
const toSearchResultOb = (tracks) => {
  return  {
    tracks: tracks
  }
}


case 'UPDATE_SEARCH_RESULT':
      return Object.assign({}, state, 
toSearchResultOb(state.tracks.concat(action.tracks)))
```

What is correct way to update component onScroll with redux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting this error because keys between component siblings need to be unique. You probably have duplicate `track.id` in your `tracks` array.

Here's an easy fix:

```
{tracks.map(track, i =>
  <Track
    key={i}
    {...track}
    //onClick={() => onTrackClick(track.id)}
    text={track.title}
    imgSrc={!track.artwork_url ? altImg : track.artwork_url}
  />
)}
```

---

If you have a look at the documentation of `map()` on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), you'll see this:

> `callback` Function that produces an element of the new Array, taking
>   three arguments:
>
> - `currentValue` The current element being processed in
>     the array.
> - `index` The index of the current element being processed in
>     the array.

So in the example above, `i` is the index of the current element. This index increments on each iteration which guarantees unique keys within that `map()`. Now you don't have to worry about what `track.id` is.

Comment: actually i am fetching data from rest api (soundcloud) with pagination and (i guess) keys is unique. is it possible that i messed up something with react redux states?

Comment: still have problem with rendering it looks a corrupted

Comment: So is the issue not solved yet? What have you managed to do so far?

Comment: i figured out, that i have problem with api callback, but it's another story. thanks!